# Send Mail From android app (using php file)

Tags: android, email, http-request

I want to send an email on button click on android app, executing a php file on the server (with mail function)

I guess I am able to connect to the server and open the file, but it does not execute
For some reason it does not work. All it displays in the android console is the following I/System.out: (HTTPLog)-Static: isSBSettingEnabled false

Below is the code

Any help will be appreceated

```
 public static void sendData() {


    try {
        URL url = new URL("http://myurl/mail.php");
        HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        conn.setReadTimeout(10000);
        conn.setConnectTimeout(15000);
        conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
        conn.setDoInput(true);
        conn.setDoOutput(true);


        HashMap<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
        params.put("name", name);
        params.put("to", mail);
        params.put("from", from);
        params.put("subject", subject);
        params.put("message", message);

       OutputStream os = conn.getOutputStream();
        BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(
                new OutputStreamWriter(os, "UTF-8"));
        writer.write(getQuery(params));
        writer.flush();
        writer.close();
        os.close();
        conn.connect();


    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}

public static String getQuery(HashMap<String, String> params) throws UnsupportedEncodingException{
    StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
    boolean first = true;
    for(Map.Entry<String, String> entry : params.entrySet()){
        if (first)
            first = false;
        else
            result.append("&");

        result.append(URLEncoder.encode(entry.getKey(), "UTF-8"));
        result.append("=");
        result.append(URLEncoder.encode(entry.getValue(), "UTF-8"));
    }

    return result.toString();
}
```

my php file is

```
<?php
     $name = $_POST['name'];
     $to = $_POST['to'];
     $from = $_POST['from'];
     $subject = $_POST['subject'];
     $message = "From: ".$name."\r\n";
     $message .= $_POST['message'];
     $headers = "From:" . $from; mail($to,$subject,$m‌​essage,$headers); 
?>
```

Comment: where's the php for this? you did tag as such. Not to mention phpmailer.

Comment: well pho is a simple one   <?php
$name = $_POST['name'];
$to = $_POST['to'];
$from = $_POST['from'];
$subject = $_POST['subject'];
$message = "From: ".$name."\r\n";
$message .= $_POST['message'];
$headers = "From:" . $from;
mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers);

?>

Comment: please don't dump code in comments. Edit your question http://stackoverflow.com/posts/38976965/edit to contain it. Plus, `mail()` is not phpmailer; two different animals altogether ;-)

Comment: sorry, new to this...ok..i use php mail, any idea why it does not work?

Comment: If it's a php issue, use error reporting. Change your `mail($to,$subject,$m‌​essage,$headers);` to `if(mail($to,$subject,$m‌​essage,$headers)){ echo "Mail sent.";} else{ echo "Error";}` - If it's an android issue, I am not the guy for this.

Comment: when i execute the file from the server it works fine, i guess its an android issue

Comment: Where are the variables `name`, `mail`, etc. coming from? My guess is that those are instance members while your `sendData()` method is a class member.

Comment: well actually the variable names just for the try, are hardcoded like this params.put("name", "justaname");

Comment: John Conde, its not a php question its an android question. php works just fine